# USB Power Delivery: How to renegotiate the existing contract

Tags: usb-pd, stm32g

STMicrosystems [UM2552](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00598101-managing-usb-power-delivery-systems-with-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) has a paragraph 4.2.2: Send request message

> A SINK must send a request message to ask for a new power level, the rest of the sequence is identical to AMS power negotiation.

How and what should I do to start the process of renegotiation? How to send USBPD_PE_Request_Ctrl/Message REQUEST?

Comment: UM2552  is incorrect/misleading. The correct call is USBPD_PE_Send_Request